# Htaccess multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, rewriting

How would I be able to have the following url working (redirecting me to the 'pretty' url)?

Visiting the following link:

```
pictures.php?genre=all&sortby=popularity
```

The rewriting part of visiting for example (localhost/mydomain/pictures/all/popularity) is working, but the only party which is not working is that whenever I visit the example above it'll redirect me to it.

My current code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pictures\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^pictures\.php?genre=([a-zA-Z]+)&sortby=([a-zA-Z]+)$ /mydomain/pictures/$1/$2 [NC,R=302,L,NE]
```

Help would be appericiated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pictures\.php\?genre=([^&]+)&sortby=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^pictures.php$ /pictures/%1/%2? [NE,NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^pictures/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /pictures.php?genre=$2&sortby=$3  [QSA,L,NC]
```